# qt set line spacing.height in QGraphicsTextItem

Tags: qt, qt4.8

I have some small graphicsitems on a canvas which need to display some text. When there is a line break, the vertical line spacing is unnecessarily large, which makes the text be drawn outside the graphic items. I have been searching for a way to set the line spacing (or maybe height) on a QGraphicsTextItem but no luck.

I have tried;

```
setHtml("<div line-height=100%>some text</div>")
```

etc.

The code where a need to set the inter line apace is:

```
class GraphicText(QtGui.QGraphicsTextItem):

def __init__(self, text='', font=None, editable=False, text_width = None, **kw):        
    super(GraphicText, self).__init__(**kw) 
    if editable:
        self.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.TextEditorInteraction)
    else:
        self.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.NoTextInteraction)
    if font:
        self.setFont(font)
    self.setText(text, text_width)

def setText(self, text = '', text_width = None):
    cw = self.textWidth()
    try:
        width = text_width or (cw if cw>0 else False) or self.parentItem().boundingRect().width()-4
    except AttributeError:
        width = 100
    self.setTextWidth(width)
    self.setHtml(text)
    rect = self.boundingRect()
    self.setPos(-rect.width() / 2, -rect.height() / 2)  # center
```

This is Python/PySide, but otherwise the API is pretty much the same as for C++. The HTML is currently passed into the **init** method as parameter 'text'. The parent of the QGraphicsTextItem is a QGraphicsItem.

Please help, this is really an eyesore.

Cheers, Lars.

Comment: anyone? should i explain more? is this impossible?

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is not reproduced when the line break is caused by `<br>` in the item's html code. Auto line break using `"test1 test2"` content and `setTextWidth` is also working fine. But when the line break is caused by `<p></p>` tags, the unnecessarily large line height shows up. I assume that this is your case. It can be easily fixed:

```
item->document()->setDefaultStyleSheet("p { margin: 0; }");
```

Note that you need to call it before setting item's content. This command doesn't affect current content.

Comment: I'm not sure you are talking about the same thing, as far as i could find QGraphicsItem does not have a method "document". I am using autobreak and setTextWidth, also 'margin' sets the space around the text, while i want to decrease the vertical distance between lines.

Comment: `document` is a method of `QGraphicsTextItem` object which is returned by `QGraphicsScene::addText`. Issue is not reproduced for me with `setTextWidth`. Can you please post some code of your current implementation?

Comment: added, my bad about the QGraphicsItem/QGraphicsTextItem misunderstanding

Comment: revisiting the problem (had a lot on my plate): the margin moves/squeezes the text but does not change the vertical distance between lines after an automatic line break "test1 test2"